# Redirect standard output to a file?

Tags: c, stdout

I want to write a function which would redirect the standard output to a file where the name of the file is "name".log where "name" is the argument to the function

```
void redirect(char *name) {
```

I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`freopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html)

```
// code copied from the link
#include <stdio.h>
...
FILE *fp;
...
fp = freopen ("/tmp/logfile", "a+", stdout);
...
```