# Using execvp with Input,Output and redirection

Tags: c, unix, redirect, exec

**In a C program**, let's say i wann use Exec functions for executing a given program, for example if i wanna just try ls -l i'll do something like

```
args[0]="ls";
args[1]="-l";
args[2]=NULL;

...
execvp("ls", args);
```

and it's all fine. Now what if i wanna also add the redirection to a file (or to stderr)? 
I'm stuck, it's obvious that adding >log.txt as a 3rd entry in the array won't work, but I don't know how to proceed.

And also, what if I wanna pass some Input parameters? What if i wanna execute a GCC command like "gcc -o out in redirection>log.txt" ?

*[update from comment:]*

It's a C program that simulate a shell which can "run strings", string that contains a command, a list o parameters, input and a redirection.

Comment: "what if I wanna pass some Input parameters?" - isn't the `args` array there for **exactly** that purpose? (if you want to **pipe** text to and from stdin/stdout, you'll need `popen()`.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect standard output to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135577/redirect-standard-output-to-a-file)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Is there a guarantee not only the stream but also the file-descriptor is the same after `freopen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set up your file descriptors as the `exec`-d process shall find them and then do the exec.
For that you need `open`, `dup2` and `close`.

All functions in the `exec`-family just replace the current process with whatever one you say.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i think i'm gettin the output part. This also applies to the input thing? Changing file descriptor of stdIn to the file i want to be the input.c of (for instance) gcc?

Comment: Yes, just set up whatever environment you want the new executable to inherit.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command in a shell:

```
char * args[] = {
  "sh",
  "-c",
  "ls -l >out.ls 2>err.ls <in.ls",
  NULL
};

...

execvp(args[0], args); 
perror("execvp() failed");
```

Comment: Sorry to ask but i'm newbie, i didn't hinted in the OP that all this has to be written in a C program, do this solution works for what i'm doing? I't a C program that simulate a shell which can "run strings", string that contains a command, a list o parameters, input and a redirection. Suppose i have to study more for the SH thing, by now i never seen sh -c ...stuff

Comment: @ro.nin: For such requirements an approach as described by *Deduplicator*'s answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23322407/694576) suit better.